# BioPerl: extract CDS error Filehandle GEN1 opened only for input

Tags: perl, bioperl, genbank

I am trying to extract CDS and corresponding amino acid sequences from GenBank file using BioPerl. The script is shown below:

```
while (my $seq_object = $in->next_seq){
for my $feat_object ($seq_object->get_SeqFeatures) {
    if ($feat_object ->primary_tag eq "CDS") {
    #   warn("all tags are ", join ("," , $feat_object->get_all_tags),"\n");        
        if ($feat_object->has_tag ("protein_id")){
            my ($protein_id) = $feat_object->get_tag_values('protein_id');
            my ($pseq) = $feat_object->get_tag_values('translation') ;
            my ($pepseq) = Bio::Seq->new(-id => $protein_id , -description => $seq_object -> accession_number,
                -seq => $pseq);
            $out->write_seq($pepseq);   
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am getting error message as:

```
Filehandle GEN1 opened only for input at /Library/Perl/5.12/Bio/Root/IO.pm line 533, <GEN0> line 148.
```

Comment: You didn't show us the whole script. How did you create `$out`? Is that a `Bio::SeqIO` object?

Comment: Yes, the $out file is a Bio::SeqIO object, which is created by: my $out = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file   => "Oct_test.fasta", -format => 'fasta');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add this as an answer since it is likely the source of the error. When creating a `Bio::SeqIO` object for output, you must follow the normal Perl rules for `open` and specify the file is for output. So, try the following:

```
my $out = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file => ">Oct_test.fasta", -format => 'fasta');
```

This is a really easy thing to forget and the error message could be a bit more descriptive.